# Hide Chrome Packaged App from App Launcher

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am creating Chrome Packaged App and need it to be hidden in Chrome App Laucher (list of apps appear when you creating the new tab, URL: chrome://apps/).

I have found "display_in_launcher" and "display_in_new_tab_page" attributes in [manifest overview](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest.html#overview) but they seems to be not working for some reason:

1. When I install App from Chrome Web Store, it just ignores fields and app is still in the App Launcher
2. When App is installed from developer mode, I see warnings:
   [image]

Is it possible to hide App from App Launcher for latest version of Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium/chromium.git;a=commitdiff;h=430aa48d0be9a1ae9ba404e8c3dc76d1148f97eb

this will help you find if your app is allowed to hide itself.
Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks! I see there is only Google Wallet app eligible to hide itself. But what is the purpose of adding that fields in manifest and publishing them in official documentation? The reason why I need this - my Chrome App is just a bridge to provide voice messaging to other Chrome Extension (voice and camera aren't allowed for Extensions but allowed to Apps for now)

Comment: i think if you could you could irritate user because they would have problems to organize their installed software. if i helped you an upvote is the thanks of stackoverflow :-) perhaps mark it as answered too.

Comment: The field is internal (i.e. for apps which are really part of the chrome system implementation) and should not be documented.As apps have capabilities that extensions don't it needs to be obvious to the user that the app is installed.